# Issue in displaying correct largest and smallest numbers

Tags: java, integer, max, exit, min

i'm very new to programming, and am attempting to create a program that will allow me to enter several integers and a separate one to quit, and upon quitting will return with the largest and smallest numbers. Everything works well except when displaying the largest and smallest numbers it only displays the quit integer, in this case -99. Here is my code, any help would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LargestSmallest
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    //identifier declarations
    int number;
    int numberend = -99;
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


    //create a Scanner object to read from the keyboard & input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //display prompts and get input
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (number == -99){ 
    System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers.");
    }else{
    //loop
    while ((number = input.nextInt()) != -99) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");

    } 
    }
    //largest & smallest
    {
    if (number > largest)
    largest = number;
    if (number < smallest)
    smallest = number;
    System.out.println("Largest:" + largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest:" + smallest);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not keeping track of the current largest and smallest numbers as they are entered in. Please see the modifications below:-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //identifier declarations
    int number;
    int numberend = -99;
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    //create a Scanner object to read from input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //display prompts and get input
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");
    while ((number = input.nextInt()) != numberend) {

        System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");

        if (number > largest) {
            largest = number;
        }
        if (number < smallest) {
            smallest = number;
        }

    }

    //largest & smallest
    System.out.println("Largest:" + largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest:" + smallest);

}
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this and still have the option to include a statement in no data is entered in the loop?

Comment: You can set a boolean if number(s) other than -99 were entered. Then use that in an if statement when you are printing out your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When inside your loop, you only save the last entered number in `number`. To exit the loop you must enter -99 which also makes that the only number you have saved. Therefore, in your code, `number` will always be -99. -99 is both larger than your `largest` (`INTEGER.MIN_VALUE`) and smaller than your `smallest` (`INTEGER.MAX_VALUE`) so this is why -99 is printed.

To solve this, you can use two variables to save the current largest and current smallest number.

You can also solve this by using a list instead. Save all the inputs in the loop in some kind of list like `ArrayList`. Then, when the user has entered -99, you must examine the list to find the largest and smallest number. This is not an optimal solution, but may help you understand what is happening.

Comment: I'll give those options a go. Thank you for the suggestion.